# How to aware of Solr cloud state change

Tags: solr, lucene

I am working on a plugin (a request handler which will start some thread for message listening) of solr which expected only work on leader shard but not replicas, I have found SolrCore will provide function to decide current core whether a leader shard, but I don't know how to be noticed when cloud changed, like a replicas changed to a leader, then I expect plugin where run on this core automatically.

It's this any way to listen solr cloud state change?